# SendGrid template transactional v3 functions Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, sendgrid-api-v3

I am using a function in Firebase to send an email every time there is a new record in Firestore, this worked fine, but it seems that SendGrid has been updated to a new version of transactional templates.

What I had before in the body of my SendGrid transaction template was:

```
nombre: {{nombre}}
email: {{email}}
celular: {{celular}}
valorPropiedad: {{valorPropiedad}}
```

This worked correctly, that is, it sent the mail (every time there was a new record in Firestore) with the data of the new record, but now it only sends the mail but arrives without any data. I think something has changed in SendGrid? or is it a theme of my function?

Before I used Angular 5 I am now using version 6.

Here the code of my function **index.js**:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const SENDGRID_API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key

const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);

exports.firestoreEmail2 = functions.firestore
    .document('domiciliarios/{domiciliarioId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        const domiciliarioId = context.params.domiciliarioId;
        const db = admin.firestore()
        return db.collection('domiciliarios').doc(domiciliarioId)
            .get()
            .then(doc => {

                const domiciliario = doc.data();

                const msg = {
                    from: 'mail1@mail.com',
                    to: 'mail2@mail.com',
                    subject: 'mySubject',
                    templateId: 'myTemplateId',
                    substitutionWrappers: ['{{', '}}'],
                    substitutions: {
                        nombre: domiciliario.nombre,
                        email: domiciliario.email,
                        celular: domiciliario.celular,
                        valorPropiedad: `US$ ${domiciliario.valorPropiedad}`,
                    }
                };

                return sgMail.send(msg)
            })
            .then(() => console.log('email sent!'))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))

});
```

Answer (score 0):

After some brute force testing this combination worked.

```js
exports.firestoreEmail = functions.firestore
    .document( 'members/{memberId}' )
    .onCreate( ( snap, context ) => {

        const member = snap.data();
        mail.setApiKey( SENDGRID_API_KEY );
        const msg = {
            to: member.email,
            from: "hello@angularfirebase.com",
            subject: "Welcome",
            templateId: "xxx",
            substitutions: {
                name: member.name,
                email: member.email,
                membershipId: member.memberId
            },
            dynamic_template_data:
            {
                name: member.name,
                email: member.email,
                membershipId: member.memberId
            }
        };

        return mail.send( msg ).then( () => console.log( 'email sent to receiver2!' ) )
            .catch( err => console.log( err ) );
    } );
```